# What is this odd message I am seeing in the macOS Terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, zsh

I am currently running macOS BigSur 11.6, and suddenly when I open Terminal there's a line that I've never seen before, it says:

```
Users/[my username]/.zshrc:2: no such user or named directory: Desktop
```

I tried looking into similar questions but noting has fixed it.

Comment: Look at this: `Users/[my username]/.zshrc:2` and specifically look in `.zshrc` at line 2; the `:2` means line 2 in `.zshrc`. Seems like the word `Desktop` is in there. If you see that in there, remove `Desktop` and the message should go away.

Comment: In particular, look at the command in that line, and fix it so it does whatever it is supposed to do. Spaces in file or directory names and no quoting could also be the reason.